# writing and reading a file of strings

Tags: java

Hi friends this is my program to create(write) an array of integer file and reading it..and it is working..now i want to create a file of Strings.Can someone help me please?

```
public class File {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        int[] array={010100101,0010010};
        OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("arun");
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            os.write(array[i]);
        }
        InputStream is=new FileInputStream("arun");
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(is.read());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "give me a solution"? - ok take this... aSolution = new Refer(FileWriter,BufferedWriter); // Returns a solution object..

Comment: ok let me try ..with thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ByteArray of the String.

```
String[] array = { "010100101", "0010010" };
try {
    // write
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("arun");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        os.write(array[i].getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    }
    // read
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("arun");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    while (( line = reader.readLine() ) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("You fucked up!");
}
```

Comment: thank you..its working ..suppose i want to change my string array as String array[]={"ram","kumar","anand"}; whether byte array of the string can be used?

Comment: if its working, please mark the answer as accepted. You can write each string you want in the array.